# Windows Phone ignora breakpoints

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, windows-phone

Como resolver o *bug* de `viewport` no Windows Phone?

Uso o código abaixo, que é para ele trocar o *background* no Smartphone, mas ele continua com o *background* de 1200px.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.jumbotron.top {background:url('../images/topo_xs.jpg');} 
}
```

Devo usar o:

```
@-ms-viewport {  width :  device-width ;  }
```

Mas não entendi muito bem como! Alguém poderia explicar?

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um bug recorrente, que a Microsoft nunca soube como atacar com coerência. Talvez agora, com o desligamento das maquinas do IE as coisas se ajustem em termos de browser por lá. Eles publicaram um update uma vez ([este](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/10/14/introducing-windows-phone-preview-for-developers/), se não me engano), dizendo que corrigiram o bug, mas, como eu disse, ele é recorrente.

Enfim, uma solução nada elegante (e talvez não atual), é a seguinte: Insira as seguintes tags no seu cabeçalho:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Juntamente com o seguinte código, também no cabeçalho:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
            "@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}"
        )
    );
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].
        appendChild(msViewportStyle);
}
```

Este código atua apenas quando o navegador é o IE10 mobile. Na maioria dos casos, ele resolve o problema do viewport. Como eu disse, é um fix não muito elegante, que foi discutido em detalhes [aqui](http://timkadlec.com/2013/01/windows-phone-8-and-device-width/).

Espero ter ajudado.